# Who is speaking the verses in Hosea 9:14-16?

Tags: hosea, morality

[Refer](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hosea%209%3A14-16&version=NIV):

> **14** Give them, LORD—
> what will you give them? Give them wombs that miscarry
> and breasts that are dry.
>
> **15** “Because of all their wickedness in Gilgal,
> I hated them there. Because of their sinful deeds,
> I will drive them out of my house. I will no longer love them;
> all their leaders are rebellious.
>
> **16** Ephraim is blighted, their root is withered,
> they yield no fruit. Even if they bear children,
> I will slay their cherished offspring

1. Who is the one who is speaking these verses?
2. Isn't it immoral to try to hurt innocent children?
3. Did it happen afterwards? Did God fulfill this?

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 2):

1. In **[Hoshea 9:14]**, the prophet "Hoshea ben-Beeri" הוֹשֵׁעַ בֶּן־בְּאֵרִי is praying a curse against the idol-worship at Gilgal by descendants of אֶפְרָיִם Ephraim.

- Rashi Commentary : https://www.sefaria.org/Hosea.9.14?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&with=Rashi&lang=bi

In [Hoshea 9:16], Hoshea presumptively claims YHVH answered his curse with a decree :

> פְּרִי בַל יַעֲשׂוּן

= "they [idol-worshipers] shall not produce fruit".

2. What moral is being taught in [Hoshea 9:14-16]?

- Exodus 20:5 as the consequence of Idol-Worship.

3. Did Hoshea's curse against Ephraim actually get fulfilled or nullified?

Nullified. **[Jeremiah 31]** states the final response from a compassionate YHVH :

> "Is Ephraim a son who is dear to Me? Is he a child who is dandled? For whenever I speak of him, I still remember him: therefore, My very innards are agitated for him; I will surely have compassion on him," says YHVH. (הֲבֵן יַקִּיר לִי אֶפְרַ֗יִם אִם יֶלֶד שַֽׁעֲשׁוּעִ֔ים כִּֽי־מִדֵּ֚י דַבְּרִי֙ בּ֔וֹ זָכֹ֥ר אֶזְכְּרֶ֖נּוּ ע֑וֹד עַל־כֵּ֗ן הָמוּ מֵעַי ל֔וֹ רַחֵ֥ם אֲרַֽחֲמֶנּוּ נְאֻם־יְהֹוָֽה)

Comment: Good answer +1.